# Wrapping block to other block thymeleaf

Tags: html, dom, layout, fragment, thymeleaf

I have two thymeleaf fragments as below

```
<div th:fragment="inputText">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div th:fragment="fieldSet"></div>
```

To include textbox into fieldset, I attempted calling it like

```
<div th:include="fieldSet">
  <th:block th:include="inputText/>
</div>
```

This does not include inputText within fieldSet. It renders only fieldSet.

Is there any way to include the fragment within fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see the entire picture of your app but it seems to me you are trying to accomplish the template inheritance here. If so I would encourage you to use '[Thymeleaf Page Layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)' which is integrated into Spring Boot Thymeleaf starter for example.

By using `Thymeleaf Page Layouts` you can organize your templates hierarchicaly having the parent page tamplate and then child tamplates for particular controller methods. This child templates can embrace parent  one and redefine different sections on parent template if needed.